# AVPlayer ReadyToPlay enum is an unresolved identifier

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

Using the Apple docs on AVPlayer, the player status should `player.status == ReadyToPlay` enum when it's ready.

I'm finding that Xcode is returning it as an unresolved identifier - I've looked through the docs from Apple, as well as previous answers from here but nothing is working.

My imports are:

```
UIKit
AVFoundation
MediaPlayer
```

here's the code:

```
//observer for AVPlayer
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String,
    ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject],
    context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if keyPath == "status" {
            println("Change at keyPath = \(keyPath) for \(object): result \(change)")
            if player.status == ReadyToPlay { 
                //unresolved identifier    
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: `if player.status == .ReadyToPlay { ... }` (You might want to read the chapter about enumerations again :)

Comment: works, please post the magic as an answer! And yes, I've hacked this app together and am kinda learning as I go :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missed the `.` from the enum:

`if player.status == .ReadyToPlay { ... }`